# How to display .mbtiles on a hosted server

Tags: hosted, openmaptiles

I am using the containerized deployment of openmaptiles. I downloaded all the basic included base maps, (dark-matter, positron, etc..). Then I downloaded the satellite tiles separately from https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/planet/ . Now I have a satellite.mbtiles that I have placed in the same location as my config.json and osm-2017-07-03-v3.6.1-planet.mbtiles. But when I hit the hosted page that shows the available tiles I have, the satellite files are not there. What do I need to do to pull these satellite files I have?

To link to the current dark-matter tiles I am using something like: http://localhost/styles/dark-matter/{z}/{x}/{y}.png , what would I need for the satellite?

Also we do have a business package purchased from these guys so nothing should hamper any of this.

TLDR: How do I utilize two .mbtiles at once, using the hosted deployment.

Comment: This could potentially be something? Maybe I need to convert all of it to folder format.

Comment: https://support.maptiler.com/i36-folder-vs-mbtiles-vs-geopackage

Comment: Add the satellite tiles as a data source in config.json.  Something like `"data": { "satellite": { "mbtiles": "filename.mbtiles" } }`